# Rails nested form field counter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I'm using https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form for my nested form. The nested form works fine, I'm now looking to have a sort of counter as I want to store the nested attributes in running number sequence. It should count+1 when a link_to_add is used and count-1 when link_to_remove

The nested portion:

```
<%= f.fields_for :instructions do |instruction| %>
  <%= instruction.label :"instruction #{instruction}" %>
  <%= instruction.text_field :instruction %>
  <%= instruction.link_to_remove "Remove this instruction" %>
<% end %>
<p>
<%= f.link_to_add "Add instruction", :instructions, class: "btn btn-small btn-primary"  %>
</p>
```

I'm thinking of using a variable to do a simple count, but i'm not sure how to trigger the increment. I've tried adding to the link_to_add, link_to_remove field but it stop with error. I'm still new to rails and pardon me if this a elementary question

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you mean? Where is the count being displayed? Why -1 on link_to_remove? I thought at first you could do with an ordered html list (ol), but now I'm not so sure what the question even is. Send over some more details and I'll try help.

Comment: @Zenph The counter answer below is close to what i have in mind but in the nested attribute context. My nested attributes is called instruction, I want to show instruction 1, instruction 2, instruction 3, etc. when I add instruction and the count should decrease when I remove them. This count will also be saved to records.

Comment: You should look into using jQuery for something like that. If you post this question (minus the ruby/rails part) into the javascript section, I'm sure you'll get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a sequence you can either use a serialize gem [e.g](https://github.com/birkirb/acts_as_serializable) or have a sequence_no field. If all you need is a counter and don't care about order (or have ordered in controller/model), though I would only to this in the 'show'...

```
<% just_a_counter = 0 %> #creates counter and sets to 0
<%= f.fields_for :instructions do |instruction| %>
  <% just_a_counter += 1 %> #increments counter
  S/No : <%= just_a_counter %> #displays
  #your other code
<% end %>
```